# How to URLEncode strings containing already URLEncoded parts in Delphi?

Tags: rest, delphi, urlencode

I'm using `TIdURI.PathEncode()` to URLEncode strings in Delphi.

Consider the string `Hi John` which URLEncodes to `Hi%20John`.

I'll put it into a TJSONObject so that the resulting JSON string is something like:

`{"Path":"Hi%20John"}` (I need Path's value to be URLEncoded).

Now my whole JSON string has to be passed as query parameter in a REST call, so I have to URLEncode it.
Calling again `TIdURI.PathEncode()` gives me that:

`%7B%22Path%22:%22Hi%20John%22%7D`

As you can see (well, if you know how to read URLEncoded paths of course) the value for the Path key has not changed this time, it's still `Hi%20John`.
Obviously, URLDecoding my REST call will give `{"Path":"Hi John"}`, which is **not** what I'm expecting.

The full URLEncoded parameter should be:

`%7B%22Path%22:%22Hi%2520John%22%7D`

which will decode to my original JSON string, giving me the correct URLEncoded value.

So how can I have strings containing URLEncoded parts to be *fully URLEncoded* in Delphi?

Comment: Easier to store strings as regular string (no URL encoding) and to pass JSON data as the document instead of URL parameters.

Comment: The backend is not under my control, I'm writing a client that must conform to that REST API.

Comment: @Bozzy the behavior you describe is intentional (see https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/176).

Comment: First, string values in JSON should not be URL-encoded. Second, as Brian said, the whole JSON string should be sent via the POST method, not GET. Which means you should need zero URL-encoding. You have the right to complain to the guy who designed that API.

Comment: Maybe you could generate the JSON string "by hand". I mean using standard string manipulation functions. The format is fairly simple and you seems to master it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau From an encoding function I'm expecting to obtain an encoded version of the passed data. It's my responsibility as a developer not to pass already encoded data, if I don't want it to be re-encoded. The function should only perform its task, not arguing about the contents I'm passing on (especially if it opens the door to false positives). If you try to zip a zipped file, it will be re-zipped... it may or may not make sense, but it's up to you, the developer (or the user) to decide, not the zip function (or in general the encoding function).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `TIdURI.PathEncode` refuses to encode parts that it thinks are already encoded.
The test is done by searching for any `%` symbol followed by two hexadecimal digits, which of course can cause false positives (i.e. the string '%face' will not be encoded, and will decode to '�ce').
This is intentional, according to the author (https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/176).

Besides the fact that a JSON should be passed via document body instead of URL parameter, one may still need to encode strings containing already encoded parts or, more likely, strings containing "false positives" like in the... %above example ;)

I've found this function works as expected:

`REST.Utils.URIEncode()`

It in turns uses `TNetEncoding.URL.Encode` passing a set of "unsafe characters" tailored to REST requests.
This function blindly encodes any % it finds to its URLEncode representation `%25`, giving a string that decodes exactly to the original one.